# Restart elasticsearch data node with shards in it

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elastic cluster with 2 nodes with each configured to act as data node as well as master node.

**Cluster Configuration:**

```
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 0
```

The shards are distributed across the 2 nodes as follows:

```
Node A : 0 2 3
Node B : 1 4
```

On Node B,shard 1 is stuck in initialization phase because it is running low on RAM.

I need to take down `Node B` so that i can increase the RAM and rejoin the cluster.So,do I need to move all shards from Node B to Node A before restarting the node? Or can I let the shards remain in the node and still restart the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about index availability during the restart period, you can restart node B. If you do care about availability, you can either:

1. Ask ES to move shards from node B to node A via [shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html)
2. Create a [replica](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) which will copy over shards from node B to node A

Comment: The downtime is not a concern. Will try and reboot and see if it works fine.